# How to use wget to download big file from google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, wget

I tried to a lot of different examples from google and it seems that none of them is avaliable.
Could you please tell me how can I achieve that? I have tried the following way which is a demo.

```
function gdrive_download () {
 CONFIRM=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1" -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')
 wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$CONFIRM&id=$1" -O $2
 rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
}

gdrive_download 120aPYqveqPx6jtssMEnLoqY0kCgVdR2fgMpb8FhFNHo test.txt
```

But it failed with the following log.

```
--2020-04-24 13:33:45--  https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=&id=120aPYqveqPx6jtssMEnLoqY0kCgVdR2fgMpb8FhFNHo
Resolving docs.google.com (docs.google.com)... 172.217.31.238, 2404:6800:4005:80c::200e
Connecting to docs.google.com (docs.google.com)|172.217.31.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-04-24 13:33:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I want to download a large image dataset from google drive. Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find the demo? The file with that ID actually doesn't exist, so the script is working. Have you tried with an ID you know it exists?

Comment: @Alessandro Yeah, I tried to use this demo to download a image dataset

Comment: Can you post the link of the demo please?